# How to secure mp4 files using PHP tokens or sessions

Tags: php

I have a directory called **`.dir`** and the sub-directory called **`.vids`** and I want to secure my all .mp4 files from direct access using php tokens or sessions so no one can embed or hyperlinked my videos, only users from my site can play or download my files.

This what I have tried so far using **`.htaccess`** this file is inside the **`.dir`** directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://my domain .com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.my domain .com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(mp4|mp3|avi)$ - [F]
```

It shows 403 forbidden when someone try to access `mydomain.com/.dir/.vids/myfile.mp4` but still I don't know how people accessing my files which makes my server overloaded and out of bandwidth, so I want to make all my files secure using php tokens or sessions then nobody gets direct access to my files and directory path.

I have found the following php code to secure stream.

```
<?php

$flussonic = 'http://flussonic-ip'; // flussonic address
$key = 'SECRETKEY'; // key from flussonic.conf file. KEEP IT IN SECRET
$lifetime = 3600 * 3; // 3 hours after link will be invalid

$stream = $_GET['stream']; // this script get streamname from a query string (script.php?stream=bbc)

$ipaddr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$desync = 300; // allowed time desync between flussonic and hosting servers in seconds
$starttime = time() - $desync;
$endtime = $starttime + $lifetime;
$salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

$hashsrt = $stream.$ipaddr.$starttime.$endtime.$key.$salt;
$hash = sha1($hashsrt);

$token = $hash.'-'.$salt.'-'.$endtime.'-'.$starttime;
$link = $flussonic.'/'.$stream.'/embed.html?token='.$token.'&remote='.$ipaddr;
$embed = '<iframe allowfullscreen style="width:640px; height:480px;" src="'.$link.'"></iframe>';

echo $embed;
?>
```

The above code was taken from **`https://flussonic.com/doc/authorization/securing-access-to-streams-authorization-with-token`**

and i tried many ways but couldn't get it to work for my need.

Any suggestions and help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first...
If you have control on your HTTP server AND if you are using apache, I would suggest to control this via mod_redirect in your .htaccess

Add this to your .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/uploads/?$
```

Of course, change /uploads/ to your mp3/mp4 directory.

Second, your approach is good, I would add more entropy with the link though.

At all costs, never in your $link or any request disclose where the files are located. Create a link that will end up looking like https://example.com/mp4loader.php?load=A_LONG_HASH_HERE

Then Validate the hash against your files and use readfile to stream the mp4 to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The referrer header is user-supplied and can be set to whatever the user wants it to be, eg:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://yoursite.com/video.mp4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Referer: http://yoursite.com/']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$res = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

and that's how anyone can scrape your videos all they want.

If you want to restrict the download of your files with PHP you need to enforce that the files can *only* be downloaded through a PHP script.

First, move the video files outside of the document root so that your web server won't serve them directly. If you want to half-ass it you can do this with config directives, but if you accidentally break the config you're back to hanging in the breeze.

eg:

```
/var/www/yoursite.com/
  |- docroot/
  |    |- foo.php
  |- videos/
       |- foo.mp4
```

Second, make a script that checks access rights and actually serves the file, eg:

```
// http://yoursite.com/foo.php?video=foo.mp4&token=1234abcd

$video = $_GET['video'];
$token = $_GET['token'];

if( ! valid_token($token) ) {
  http_response_code(401);
  exit();
}
if( ! valid_and_safe_video_name($video) ) {
  http_response_code(400);
  exit();
}

$video_path = '../videos/' . $video;

header('Content-Type: video/whatever');
readfile($video_path);
```

Alternatively, if your server supports `X-Sendfile` you can use that to make Apache handle reading out the file rather than tying up a PHP process.

```
// replaces readfile()
header('X-Sendfile: ' . $video_file);
```